# Lost executable +x permissions after home folder encryption

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I have encrypted my home folder, where I have many compiled installations of Qt, and now every executable file in all those installations have lost their +x flag in permissions, and I can't execute them or use them.

Is there a way to fix this and find executable files and restore the permissions?

I believe there should be a way, even though I don't know it; since Nautilus (Ubuntu file explorer) seem to properly be able to give correct icons for executables. How can it know that this file is an executable so that it would give it the right icon?

Comment: The icons your file browser is using are (mostly) based on the same principle as the `file` command: Magic numbers at the beginning of a file. Setting that aside, could you detail the process you used to encrypt your home folder?

Comment: @DanielB Thank you for the info on `file` command. The encryption is done using this tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/